# Adding to a table with foreign keys

Tags: php, mysql

To simplify the problem, I have three tables:

```
Books(isbn, title, author_id, pub_id)

Authors(id, first_name, last_name)

Publishers(pub_id, name)
```

Books has two foreign keys, author_id and pub_id. They are set to "restrict" on both delete and update, which I assume means that it stops you if you try to delete or alter a line from the Authors or Publishers table while it's being used by books.

I want to add a new book into table Books, but each time I try I get:

> Error: SQL Error:  Errno: 1452 Error: Cannot add or update a child
>   row: a foreign key constraint fails `(emilyc_library.Books,
>   CONSTRAINT publisher_foreign_key FOREIGN KEY (pub_id) REFERENCES
>   Publishers (pub_id))`

The same thing happens when I disable the pub_id foreign key and try with just author_id.

Everything works when I disable both foreign keys.

I've poked around and mostly seen the hack-y answer to disable your foreign keys when you want to insert, which both seems impractical and defeats the purpose of foreign key constraints.

What's causing this problem? Is it really the design of MySQL that you can't update into a table with foreign key constraints?

EDIT: My insert code looks like this:

In addbooksrv.php:

```
<?php
include 'dbconnect.php';
$sql = "insert into Books (isbn,name,author_id,pub_id) values
('" .
  $_REQUEST["isbn"] . "','" .
  $_REQUEST["name"] . "','" .
  $_REQUEST["author_id"] . "','" .
  $_REQUEST["pub_id"] . 
"')";

if (!$result = $mysqli->query($sql)) {
    echo "Error: SQL Error: </br>";
    echo "Errno: " . $mysqli->errno . "</br>";
    echo "Error: " . $mysqli->error . "</br>";

    exit;
}
?>
```

In addbookclt.php, author_id and pub_id have choose boxes that display the available IDs:

```
<table>
<form action="addbooksrv.php">
ISBN: <input type="int" name="isbn"/></br>
Book: <input type="text" name="name"/></br>
Author: <select author_id="author_id"/>
<?php
    include "dbconnect.php";
    $sql = "select * from Authors";

    $result = myquery($mysqli,$sql);

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
      echo "<option value = '" . $row["author_id"] . "'>" .  $row["id"] . "
            </option>";
    }

?>
</select>
</br>

Publisher: <select pub_id="pub_id"/>
<?php
    $sql = "select * from Publishers";

    $result = myquery($mysqli,$sql);

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
      echo "<option value = '" . $row["pub_id"] . "'>" .  $row["pub_id"] . "
            </option>";
    }

?>
</select>
</br>
<input type="submit"/>
</form>
</table>
```

Comment: well this is self explanatory, you try to add book with pub_id that doesn't exists in Publishers

Comment: I've gone through all of those little issues - are the variable names spelled right, are you adding a pub_id that exists - and made sure they're all correct. In this case I have five publishers and five authors, both labeled 1-5, and I've been testing it by adding '1' to both fields. Edit: It does help to know that this isn't supposed to happen, though!

Comment: Can you show us your insert query?

Comment: @Peter it's updated now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok now when you added all code everything is clear

```
<select author_id="author_id"/>
<select pub_id="pub_id"/>
```

should be

```
<select name="author_id">
<select name="pub_id">
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is in the HTML you are building.  For example you've got the publishers select as the following:

```
<select pub_id="pub_id"/>
```

That's opening and closing a `<select>` in one go.  The other issue is you don't have a `name` attribute to your select elements, which means it can't reference them.  Ultimately your queries are trying to insert NULL into the foreign key columns, rather than an allowed value.

Use `<select name="pub_id">` for publishers and make the relevant changes also to authors.